# How To toggle a single triangle class when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple spans that use the same class, I am trying to toggle a triangle downwards when the user clicks on it.I have that working as shown bellow.However when you click on one triangle to be toggled all the triangles on the page gets toggled, how do i only toggle a single class at a time. for example if i click on "click me 1" thats the only class that should drop the triangle down instead of it toggling all the classes.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.Toggle', function () {

           
            //$('.triangle').toggleClass("triangle-down");
                 $(this).toggleClass("triangle-down"); //tried

           });
```

```css
.triangle {
    margin-top: -29px;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 6px solid red;
    margin-left: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.triangle-down {
     transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Toggle">
<span >
<input type="checkbox " style="display:none">
</span>
<span ><div style="font-size: 11px;" class="triangle" >
</div></span><span style="margin-left:14px;">Click ME 1</span>
<br/>
<span >
<input type="checkbox " style="display:none">
</span>
<span ><div style="font-size: 11px;" class="triangle" >
</div></span><span style="margin-left:14px;">Click ME 2</span>
<br/>
<span >
<input type="checkbox " style="display:none">
</span>
<span ><div style="font-size: 11px;" class="triangle" >
</div></span><span style="margin-left:14px;">Click ME 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Use: $(this).toggleClass("triangle-down");

Comment: this question caught my attention, I thought was this also but since it was in the click of the body it wasn't going to work. So glad to see the response. I learned something new!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting `$('.triangle')`,  you are selecting all the elements with class triangle.

You need to get a reference of the triangle from the element that has been clicked. In this case it can be achieved by

```
$('body').on('click', '.Toggle', function (e) {
    // If user can click on triangle element itself
    $(e.target).closest('.triangle').toggleClass("triangle-down");
    // If user has to click on CLICK ME Button
    $(e.target).prev().find('.triangle').toggleClass("triangle-down");
});
```

If you want to update triangle when clicked on both triangle and CLICK ME

```
$('body').on('click', '.Toggle', function (e) {
    var triangle = $(e.target).closest('.triangle');
    if (!triangle.length) {
        triangle = $(e.target).prev().find('.triangle');
    }
    triangle.toggleClass("triangle-down");
});
```

> PS: I would recommend you to check jquery documentation to get better
>   idea about what `closest`, `prev` and `find` methods do and what is
>   `e.target`

Comment: Thanks i will check that out

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '.Toggle', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("triangle-down");
});
```

Comment: Hi,i have tried that and it doesnt work,i have updated my post to show what it does